# Problem in data loading with np.loadtxt (wrong column number)

Tags: python, numpy

I tried to use np.loadtxt to read my data like below.

```
2.603553660898443312e-01 -4.895428240208468673e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.692973140530490639e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 3.309641871406231173e-02 -1.574395712069615039e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 3.977061440569500950e-01 -2.000389173955275712e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -7.194669563029079118e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -3.294363921750940172e-01 -1.485494422917376545e+00 7.649974176928737712e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.986861020981289583e+00 7.399070318008985625e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-1.302130350080599852e+00 -7.078641653060913086e-01 -9.388087873448814902e-01 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.385707122325310126e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 -7.928430014705414308e-01 -2.159190177917480469e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 2.883860662351565018e-01 -2.027121847023165113e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -1.888036672463445642e+00 -6.246457099914550781e-01 5.758177529522195970e-01 -1.185064592717629539e+00 9.893518332816638727e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.892748844156156407e+00 -1.284842542619519135e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-1.538764411852037127e-02 7.593689560890197754e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 -1.154888153076171875e+00 -1.546543728467292489e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 -5.428010565243505947e-02 -2.159190177917480469e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 4.242245847368125711e-01 -2.046791196912447486e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -7.635774726915584010e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -4.333124629278791162e-01 -1.450526959381636338e+00 7.018959344055138994e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.274224971284406704e+00 7.430358545514238466e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
2.530201577179368999e-01 -7.078641653060913086e-01 -1.298411276617180699e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 -1.154888153076171875e+00 -1.529642983605434603e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 1.760995636934797326e-01 -9.454957842826843262e-01 -5.816161632537841797e-01 6.571330636461157892e-01 -1.851169310454455985e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -7.931913446396373635e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 7.853549798057968268e-02 -1.641357050606170542e+00 5.275419207402499699e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 3.114833498626482289e+00 3.142607778358770254e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-2.726682561048570097e-01 7.593689560890197754e-01 -1.702500070876577842e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -7.462093822852050584e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 -4.179292554235939372e-01 -9.454957842826843262e-01 -5.816161632537841797e-01 2.738389778646722061e-01 -1.743650601780387444e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -7.007318644649570549e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -4.905898518278625775e-01 -1.616954997625343449e+00 4.244871861106171984e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.247822050133649441e+00 1.673627418840741565e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-1.705524915647234907e-01 -7.078641653060913086e-01 -3.933271873732819279e-01 -1.258912324905395508e+00 -1.878358372040451682e-02 -1.480277627192263523e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 -1.335736040030894856e-01 -9.454957842826843262e-01 -5.816161632537841797e-01 -3.907166957047136790e-02 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -4.242789597938537161e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -6.296429825424300075e-01 -1.699251060596407736e+00 5.231217414104525343e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 8.884990864881863182e-01 8.394160434091983980e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
8.414418167458778686e-02 -2.302190490777209220e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -2.233080518360677225e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 2.415446738051176823e-01 -9.454957842826843262e-01 -5.816161632537841797e-01 1.330483708311234636e+00 -1.264024309558561043e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -1.549462342173952845e+00 -6.246457099914550781e-01 3.826412790242795237e-01 -1.227891439044842103e+00 2.145936699533110836e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.235969684050001183e+00 8.251928826112742144e-02 -1.665471792221069336e+00
1.102250310218136686e+00 7.593689560890197754e-01 -1.091183800024290163e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -2.074930244873870233e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 1.465331029484069791e+00 -1.430153656426094155e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 2.210483287104787198e-01 -1.842230363534487880e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -2.727518567013142992e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -1.056191336109992385e+00 -1.842855346187619148e+00 6.720207713606580757e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.625321359660649723e+00 2.343762040524264290e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-4.923382933168919395e-01 -7.078641653060913086e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -9.043386263538696346e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 9.056019200954330550e-01 -2.159190177917480469e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 4.120651371168520538e-01 -1.202602039254219379e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -4.463115558608705680e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -2.465611681105926156e-01 -2.418160461810230366e+00 3.153506403718202011e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.837756265875313266e+00 4.819243156757043733e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
7.272601393316203700e-01 -2.300621518049953129e-01 -9.760004398931230174e-01 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.361627661659024380e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 -2.700336699475488489e-01 -2.029818614025540757e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 1.295966250284096732e+00 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 2.098972797393798828e-01 3.736804127693176270e-01 -4.579203066455626026e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -4.260846814416792694e-01 -1.517599859149341146e+00 5.556466724576389904e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.155389563541422415e+00 6.256669627004781686e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
1.632822646427501745e+00 -5.623250876630545569e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 8.367893089430193665e-02 -4.650408477666542195e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 1.175758481762884999e+00 -9.716792425561205926e-01 -5.816161632537841797e-01 9.509830627847343232e-01 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 1.736771247993560141e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -1.333171454035249059e-01 -1.133441729488295691e+00 6.238210711964906618e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.506947456997861146e+00 1.216950644645044211e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
6.969873935433866128e-04 -3.903050081244650582e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 5.347453416880512678e-02 -9.789908358441286040e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 9.286523183191518482e-01 -1.214563993118293883e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 -2.854013674604540807e-01 -2.045514827647296308e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 2.098972797393798828e-01 3.736804127693176270e-01 -1.759843556620368954e+00 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -2.870594647448480030e-01 -1.553740398545384593e+00 1.602377924705553403e+00 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.814247658835527410e+00 4.475213566117427488e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-4.151392767789610638e-01 1.440440236519151540e-01 -1.298010593262960199e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -2.104797214062689381e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 4.459293405586593484e-01 -1.595314300059556212e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 4.847042176475293007e-01 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 7.039920779232275438e-02 -6.246457099914550781e-01 8.133878589505812995e-01 -1.479315724748465843e+00 1.236684672593987289e+00 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.139131585114901757e+00 -7.202429440018828788e-02 -1.665471792221069336e+00
1.420074197569520802e-01 -2.288263332875498934e-01 -1.132133522309169082e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.155158613415481872e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 7.078138972011696062e-01 -2.068466977335940538e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 3.532272618000333875e-01 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -1.112874297636844423e+00 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -1.979109506106755192e-02 -8.684234217792428101e-01 2.747399054119102346e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.249448834345347592e+00 5.760643339458634271e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-8.789007481847324610e-02 -4.839818985663431050e-01 -1.625775166077927159e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.381811408848409584e-01 -7.056640061929307928e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 -5.257895907132947855e-01 -2.119834248137577148e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 -4.384247260685396608e-01 -1.682645422255073520e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 1.878001933600839946e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -7.823728870493153187e-02 -1.671770517190221517e+00 1.703538000021825871e+00 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.572267051716103037e+00 2.619185141009520379e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
1.620029147701762762e+00 -4.186652269761921563e-02 -1.690031189342144247e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.772061125629339040e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 -2.261350165979045604e-02 -1.623823211626151286e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 3.218979472406405251e-01 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -9.845511514584495139e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 1.176023071476889115e+00 -2.346918687838878803e+00 -6.121454837619668549e-02 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.870331153785868672e+00 1.010830411388754291e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
3.452628406873124445e-01 -3.322626184884560074e-01 -1.547153873348277697e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.547489992299857287e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 1.093331733408774015e-01 -1.594287182900631539e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 6.280679529341063327e-01 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 -1.305338484450615288e+00 -7.617218951978775854e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -4.273783596939032536e-01 -1.775468028995908831e+00 8.527512755285724388e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.991101796346803843e+00 5.306754667227668865e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
-2.673182938643026696e-01 -7.078641653060913086e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -7.215357136198484733e-01 1.273696422576904297e+00 -1.202584135477882565e+00 -1.774783105631543068e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 2.651677315872162377e-01 -1.637549180703332219e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -4.626194026604988352e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -1.910092496620663383e-01 -6.213563695339414661e-01 1.063001555613360516e+00 4.254773855209350586e-01 8.305248022079467773e-01 -7.976613814547941494e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
2.164021240325763262e+00 -6.286970263484337185e-01 -1.716421842575073242e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.390203237533569336e-01 -1.198670076171520105e+00 1.273696422576904297e+00 3.305594095920846853e-01 -1.681574983400655698e+00 -5.816161632537841797e-01 1.557135501038261260e+00 -2.077498674392700195e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -1.987184628894896665e+00 -6.246457099914550781e-01 1.021557812723548730e+00 -1.398266162631328191e+00 1.515991635387667902e+00 4.254773855209350586e-01 2.497397173739365428e+00 -2.794518388281934662e+00 -1.665471792221069336e+00
1.419768239396037302e-01 -3.178750151354216014e-01 -1.474913088195167976e+00 -1.258912324905395508e+00 1.101487532810647846e-01 -1.456694743395003266e+00 2.059759378433227539e+00 3.076573184349348788e-02 -1.560192493674076974e+00 4.038435220718383789e-02 5.027152760892119598e-01 -1.890080033053601838e+00 -1.301198482513427734e+00 1.091637611389160156e+00 3.736804127693176270e-01 -6.933332441084434361e-01 -6.246457099914550781e-01 -2.855877946331054074e-01 -1.437997817535657363e+00 6.779475822218943293e-01 4.254773855209350586e-01 1.960408831860432022e+00 6.626344760302590453e-01 -1.665471792221069336e+00
```

But I consistently got the error which said

```
latent = np.loadtxt(args.input)
file "/home/sejeong/anaconda3/envs/PSJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1139, in loadtxt
for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
file "/home/sejeong/anaconda3/envs/PSJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1064, in read_data
% line_num)
ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 14
```

I don't know the reason why the error occurred because I can't find any problems in line 14.
Is there anyway to fix this problem?
Thank you.

=========================================

When I change np.loadtxt to np.genfromtxt I got the error like below.

```
latent = np.genfromtxt(args.input)
File "/home/sejeong/anaconda3/envs/PSJ/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 2080, in genfromtxt
raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #14 (got 9 columns instead of 24)
```

There are also 24 columns in line 14, but this error occur continuously.
Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: Given it’s a text file, have a look in a text editor and try to determine the difference in line 14 (or there-about), relative to surrounding lines.  As you’ve already deduced; there is likely extra / missing column values(s).

Comment: Did you inspect what's actually happened in line 14?

Comment: @MHHabib Yes. There were no problems.

Comment: @S3DEV Already, I had a look the file with text editor but I couldn't find any differences.

Comment: I found that some lines are loaded only some parts. It will be the cause of my problem. But I don't know the reason. @S3DEV

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that args.input really delivers the file you expected? I would have written a comment but my reputation is not sufficient.

So far I could not reproduce the errors you got with the provided data. I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('input', type=str, nargs='?', default='data.txt',
                   help='filename')

args = parser.parse_args()

data = np.loadtxt(args.input)

print(f'shape: {data.shape}')

for line in data:
    if len(line) != 24:
        print('found line of length different from 24')
```

Execution prints out:

```
shape: (20, 24)
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help!!! I found the reason of the errors. I did mistakes when I run shell file which load the input data to python file. I fixed it thanks to your help.